# unable to use jsts with Node

Tags: node.js, typescript

I am trying to use the [JSTS](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts) NPM library in a Node / TypeScript project.

I've followed the instructions given [here](https://github.com/bjornharrtell/jsts#readme).
When I try to import a module like so:

```
import GeoJSONReader from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader.js'
```

I get:

> TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: src/index.ts:1:27 - error
> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module
> 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader.js'.
> '/home/username/test/node_modules/jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader.js'
> implicitly has an 'any' type.   Try `npm i --save-dev @types/jsts` if
> it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader.js';`
>
> 1 import GeoJSONReader from
> 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader.js'

I've tried both suggestions but the error message remains the same.

If I try to silence the TypeScript by adding a `//@ts-expect-error` to silence the TypeScript, i.e. like so:

```
// @ts-expect-error
import GeoJSONReader from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader.js'
const r = new GeoJSONReader();
```

... this results in the following error which is very confusing as it asks you to use `import` where in fact the code does use `import`.

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module: /home/mperdikeas/test/node_modules/jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader.js
require() of ES modules is not supported.
require() of /home/mperdikeas/test/node_modules/jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader.js from /home/mperdikeas/test/src/index.ts is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules.
Instead rename GeoJSONReader.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from /home/mperdikeas/test/node_modules/jsts/package.json.

    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)
    at Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1102:13)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .js] (/home/mperdikeas/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1587:43)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:12)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:101:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/mperdikeas/test/src/index.ts:2:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Module.m._compile (/home/mperdikeas/test/node_modules/ts-node/src/index.ts:1597:23) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

I am using:

```
$ npm --version
8.15.0
$ node -v
v14.20.0
```

Code is simply:

```
import GeoJSONReader from 'jsts/org/locationtech/jts/io/GeoJSONReader.js'
console.log('hello World!');
```

`tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {

    "target": "es2016",                      
    "lib": ["es6"],                          

    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "rootDir": "src",                        
    "resolveJsonModule": true,               

    "allowJs": true,                         
    "outDir": "build",                       
    "esModuleInterop": true,                 
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,

    "strict": true,                          
    "noImplicitAny": true,                   
    "skipLibCheck": true                     
  }
}
```

`package.json` is:

```
{
  "name": "archetype-ts-node",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "tsc",
    "_raze": "rimraf ./node_modules",
    "clean": "rimraf ./build",
    "raze": "run-s clean _raze",
    "exec": "npx ./build/index.js",
    "start": "run-s build exec ",
    "start:dev": "nodemon"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/mperdikeas/archetype-ts-node.git"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/mperdikeas/archetype-ts-node/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/mperdikeas/archetype-ts-node#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.5",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^10.8.2",
    "typescript": "^4.7.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "jsts": "^2.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried -- as the error message suggests -- to install the typings for jsts via `npm i --save-dev @types/jsts`

Comment: @derpirscher Yes, I should have clarified that. Makes no difference.

Comment: that project is using ESM ("type": "module" in package.json) but your project doesn't. So you can't use it directly.  Look for options in tsconfig that will transpile esm into commonjs.